# uploading image using curl and php

Tags: php, post, curl

Im trying to post an image to an api provided by dlvr.it ,
Im running the same code on my local server with no errors, the image is posted alright, but when i upload the same image, and the same code to my server, the api returns to me a 106 error Image too large or wrong type. but it has no sense, its the same image that is being uploaded on my local server

this is my code:

```
$url = 'http://api.dlvr.it/1/postToRoute.' . $format;


    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
    //curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, dirname(__FILE__).'/test.cookie'); // replace this with /tmp or something like that
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    /*curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true);

    $verbose = fopen('php://temp', 'rw+');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_STDERR, $verbose);*/



    $data = array(
        'key' => $this->get_key(),
        'id' => 769605,
        'msg' => "$msg",
      'media' =>'@' . realpath('tempimages/NlTtSYaVoKcLIgt11313XUeEiHfvOgnHfYU.jpg')




    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);



    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    var_dump($result);
 if ($result === FALSE) {
  printf("cUrl error (#%d): %s<br>\n", curl_errno($ch),
       htmlspecialchars(curl_error($ch)));
  }

  /*rewind($verbose);
  $verboseLog = stream_get_contents($verbose);

  echo "Verbose information:\n<pre>", htmlspecialchars($verboseLog), "      </pre>\n";*/
```

any ideas?